# Buck converter with interleave yields wrong output voltage in simulation

Tags: ltspice, simulation, buck

> [image]

> [image: schematic]

It isn't obvious to me how to solve this by hand (if anyone knows I am very interested), so I thought of simulating it instead. We need to know some values, though:

**Duty cycle of switch A** \$D_A = \frac{V_{in}}{V_{out}} = \frac{30\text{V}}{130\text{V}} = \frac{3}{13}\$

**Duty cycle of switch B** \$D_B = 1-D_A = \frac{10}{13} \$

**Switching period** \$T=\frac{1}{f_{sw}} = \frac{1}{350\text{kHz}} = 2.857\text{us} \$

**Inductor values** \$L_1 = L\cdot 1.2 = 18\text{uH}\$, \$L_2 = L \cdot 0.8 = 12\text{uH} \$

SW_A and SW_B must not conduct simultaneously, so SW_B has to be delayed by \$\tau = D_AT \$. Using these values in a simulation should give me what I'm looking for - but it is not. For some reason, the voltage in the simulation is oscillating and is not 30V. Why do I not get the desired 30V at the output? Note that I have chosen generic values for \$C_1 \$ and \$R_{\text{load}} \$ and have used switches as ideal MOSFETS in the LTspice simulation.

[image]

Comment: You need to load it enough to put it into CCM for the output to become 30 V without any regulation. Your circuit is open loop.

Comment: Also, please add freewheeling diode across your switches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The \$T_{ON}\$ time is \$\frac{1}{350kHz} \times \frac{30}{130} = 0.6593µs\$.

The current ramp will be equal:

\$ΔI_L = \frac{V_L}{L} \times T_{ON} = \frac{100V}{15µH}*0.6593µs = 4.395A\$.

Thus the load current should be large than **4.395A** (because we have two phases), thus **RL_min = 6.8Ω** to stay in CCM.
And your simulation does not work because you are wrongly controlled the switches. The duty cycle should be the same in both switches (A and B). Try to set the same duty cycle in both switches. And add to switch B Tdelay = 0.7µs. Also do not forget to add a freewheeling diode across your switches.

[image]

[image]

The synchronous switch version

[image]

[image]

LTspcie file (.asc)

```
Version 4
SHEET 1 1004 760
WIRE -240 32 -304 32
WIRE 32 32 -240 32
WIRE 288 32 32 32
WIRE 32 64 32 32
WIRE 288 64 288 32
WIRE -64 80 -80 80
WIRE -16 80 -64 80
WIRE 208 80 192 80
WIRE 240 80 208 80
WIRE -304 96 -304 32
WIRE 32 192 32 144
WIRE 96 192 32 192
WIRE 416 192 96 192
WIRE 672 192 496 192
WIRE -64 224 -64 80
WIRE -304 240 -304 176
WIRE 208 240 208 80
WIRE 288 272 288 144
WIRE 320 272 288 272
WIRE 416 272 320 272
WIRE 672 272 672 192
WIRE 672 272 496 272
WIRE 752 272 672 272
WIRE 784 272 752 272
WIRE 784 288 784 272
WIRE 32 304 32 192
WIRE 288 304 288 272
WIRE -64 320 -64 288
WIRE -16 320 -64 320
WIRE 208 320 208 304
WIRE 240 320 208 320
WIRE 672 320 672 272
WIRE -352 368 -352 336
WIRE -224 368 -224 352
WIRE 784 416 784 368
WIRE 32 432 32 384
WIRE 288 432 288 384
WIRE 672 432 672 384
WIRE -352 480 -352 448
WIRE -224 480 -224 448
FLAG 784 416 0
FLAG 672 432 0
FLAG 32 432 0
FLAG 288 432 0
FLAG -304 240 0
FLAG 240 368 0
FLAG -16 368 0
FLAG -16 128 0
FLAG 240 128 0
FLAG -80 80 Vs1
FLAG 192 80 Vs2
FLAG -224 480 0
FLAG -352 480 0
FLAG -352 336 Vs1
FLAG -224 352 Vs2
FLAG 752 272 out
FLAG -240 32 Vin
FLAG 96 192 Ph1
FLAG 320 272 Ph2
SYMBOL Lt\\sw 32 160 M180
SYMATTR InstName S1
SYMBOL Lt\\sw 288 160 M180
SYMATTR InstName S2
SYMBOL Lt\\sw 32 400 M180
SYMATTR InstName S3
SYMBOL Lt\\sw 288 400 M180
SYMATTR InstName S4
SYMBOL ind 400 208 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L1
SYMATTR Value 15uH
SYMBOL ind 400 288 R270
WINDOW 0 32 56 VTop 2
WINDOW 3 5 56 VBottom 2
SYMATTR InstName L2
SYMATTR Value 15uH
SYMBOL res 768 272 R0
SYMATTR InstName R1
SYMATTR Value 6
SYMBOL cap 656 320 R0
SYMATTR InstName C1
SYMATTR Value 5uF
SYMBOL Lt\\voltage -304 80 R0
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName V1
SYMATTR Value 100
SYMBOL Lt\\voltage -352 352 R0
WINDOW 3 -298 183 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 1 0 1n 1n {D*1/F} {1/F})
SYMATTR InstName V2
SYMBOL Lt\\voltage -224 352 R0
WINDOW 3 -27 182 Left 2
WINDOW 123 0 0 Left 2
WINDOW 39 0 0 Left 2
SYMATTR Value PULSE(0 1 {(1/F)/Phase} 1n 1n {D * 1/F} {1/F})
SYMATTR InstName V3
SYMBOL Digital\\inv 0 224 R90
WINDOW 3 8 60 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName A1
SYMBOL Digital\\inv 272 240 R90
WINDOW 3 8 60 Left 2
SYMATTR InstName A2
TEXT 312 552 Left 2 !.model sw sw(Ron =1m, Roff=10Meg, Vt=0.5, Vh=-0.5)
TEXT -472 608 Left 2 !.param D 0.3
TEXT -472 648 Left 2 !.param F 350k
TEXT -472 720 Left 2 !.tran 1m
TEXT 320 520 Left 2 !.model Did D(Vfwd =1m, Ron=1m)
TEXT -472 680 Left 2 !.param Phase 2
```

Comment: So that's where I went wrong. Both switch A and B have to have the same duty cycle. And of course I needed to avoid shoot through. Thanks a lot for this upclearing answer. And a big sorry to @aconcernedcitizen for (again) wasting a lot of his time on my incompetence with LTspice...

Comment: Of course, you can use synchronous switches. In the synchronous mode, you don't need freewheeling diodes. Because the synchronous converter is always in CCM. But the lower switch B (for L1 inductor) needs to be changed to switch A and vice versa for L2 coil switches (upper and lower need to be switch B).

Comment: @G36 You don’t with real switches, but LTspice does not like the “discontinuity” with no obvious way for the current to flow, and with standard switch off state set to gigaohm, you see MV glitches. I recommend freewheeling diodes.